# How to get translation from other module in PrestaShop?

Tags: php, prestashop

I have a "baseModule" PrestaShop module and a bunch of "baseExtensionModule[n]" modules.

So, in order to avoid redundancy, I would like to reuse some translation from "baseModule" within the others.

I have checked Translate::getModuleTranslation() and it looks like ModuleCore::l() does not offer the possibility to pass a module name and forward it to the first one.

Any workaround you may know for this?

I guess that getting the "baseModule" module instance would be another way to do it - using it's l() method instead of the current $this->l. How can I get an instance for another module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little snippet I use in my ajax files:

```
$module_name = 'mymodule';

if (Module::isInstalled($module_name) && Module::isEnabled($module_name))
{
    $mod = Module::getInstanceByName($module_name);

    if (method_exists($mod, 'doSomething'))
        $mod->doSomething();
}
```

Now you could use `Module::getInstanceByName('mymodule')->l('string')`, but I almost sure it would work.

This is because translations controller scans for `$this->l\((.*)\)` inside module folder using regex and adds the translatable strings to a file. Since `Module::getInstanceByName('modulename')->l('')` doesn't  match this pattern, strings wouldn't even be recognized.

If you want the string to accessible via `Module::getInstanceByName('modulename')->l('string1')`, `$this->l('string1')` must exist inside base module file, it will scanned and added to translations.

Another way I can recommend is to use a static variable to hold your translations:

```
public static $l = array();

public function __construct()
{
    ...
    $this->init();
}

public function init()
{
   if (self::isInstalled($this->name)) {
      self::$l = array(
         'string1' => $this->l('string1'),
      );
   }
}
```

Then use `Module::getInstanceByName` to get the instance and access the static variable.

I actually use this way to translate model field names, because there aren't many alternatives.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, the very first piece of code it's all I need. The only thing that I have to do is call $this->l('..') with strings I need in "baseModule", and for this base module I will handle translations in admin. Ultimately, though, I will have them available in context of other modules, via instance got by name. So, bottom line, it solves what I need: translate in one base module and use translations in all others that extend it's functionality.