# PrestaShop: Translating overrided controller

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've created a module that overrides an AdminProductController.php and make a new bulk_action.

```
<?php
class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->bulk_actions['setprice'] = array(
            'text' => $this->l('Set a price for selected'),
            'icon' => 'icon-price',
        );
    }
}
```

Now I need to translate the action text and distribute that translation with module.
The problem is that I don't see the original text inside modules translation instead it is visible in back-office translations.

So, is there any way to add this string to module translations not to back-office translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem description I've found here: [How to get translation from other module in PrestaShop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952621/how-to-get-translation-from-other-module-in-prestashop)

> This is because translations controller scans for $this->l((.*)) inside module folder using regex and adds the translatable strings to a file
>   So we should in module do something like this:

```
class MyModule extends Module
{

    public static $l = null;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this::$l = $this->l('Set a price for selected');
    }
}
```

Than in controller we can do what was suggested by @TheDrot:

```
class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $module = Module::getInstanceByName('modulename');
        $this->bulk_actions['setprice'] = array(
            'text' => $module->l('Set a price for selected'),
            'icon' => 'icon-price',
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by creating an instance of a module you want the translation to be in.

```
class AdminProductsController extends AdminProductsControllerCore
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $module = Module::getInstanceByName('modulename');
        $this->bulk_actions['setprice'] = array(
            'text' => $module->l('Set a price for selected'),
            'icon' => 'icon-price',
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: So far it did not help. The phrase had disappeaed from backoffice tab but did not appear in modules tab

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code in place of $this->l('Set a price for selected')

Translate::getModuleTranslation(YOUR_MODULE_NAME, 'Set a price for selected', FILE_NAME);