# Error Click total subscriber

Tags: php, prestashop-1.7

I m using the CMD prestashop 1.7.2.4 , when i click to  'total subscriber' , i have this error :

```
[PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file: /home/lecoindedg/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3224
Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function isUsingNewTranslationSystem() on boolean in /home/lecoindedg/www/controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php:1403 Stack trace: #0 /home/lecoindedg/www/classes/controller/AdminController.php(2849): AdminModulesControllerCore->initModal() #1 /home/lecoindedg/www/classes/controller/Controller.php(186): AdminControllerCore->init() #2 /home/lecoindedg/www/classes/Dispatcher.php(379): ControllerCore->run() #3 /home/lecoindedg/www/admin792ivsbt0/index.php(95): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #4 {main} Next LogicException: Request stack is empty in /home/lecoindedg/www/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3224 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->terminateWithException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError)) #1 /home/lecoindedg/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php(606): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableE
```

[image]

Any clue thxs ?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Prestashop and they have been notified in: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/628397-total-subscribers-on-the-dashboard-error/. The bug itself seems related to translation causes an issue with the module: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952621/how-to-get-translation-from-other-module-in-prestashop I would suggest waiting for Prestashop to come up with a solution or possibly overwrite this value manually with the correct error handling as documented in the SO question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution :

On the file : views/templates/hook/dashboard_zone_one.tpl

Change :

```
-               <span class="data_label"><a href="{$link->getAdminLink('AdminModules')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}&amp;configure=blocknewsletter&amp;module_name=blocknewsletter">{l s='Total Subscribers' d='Modules.Dashactivity.Admin'}</a></span>
+               <span class="data_label"><a href="{$link->getAdminLink('AdminModules')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}&amp;configure=ps_emailsubscription&amp;module_name=ps_emailsubscription">{l s='Total Subscribers' d='Modules.Dashactivity.Admin'}</a></span>
```

Adjusted Dashboard Total subscribers link to point to ps_emailsubscription configuration page instead of blocknewsletter that doesn't exists anymore.